# Printing numbers in correct way

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, button, xmlhttprequest

I'm getting data from 'http://p****.i*****.fi/food.txt' which is just numbers under each other like this, 1
   2
   3
   4, but it prints those numbers next to each other like this 1 2 3 4, is there a way to print it as it is ?

```js
function Doc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://p****.i*****.fi/food.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
<button type="button" onclick="Doc()">Content</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this CSS property:

```
white-space: pre;
```

#### Demo

```css
.pre {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="pre">With pre:
1
2
3
4
</div>
<div>Without pre:
1
2
3
4
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an HTML break in between the numbers should put the numbers on their own lines. You may have to parse the data from link before displaying it.

ex. `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "1 <br> 2 <br> 3 <br> 4"`

Answer (score -1):

loop through each number and add \n after each number, that will force the next number on the next line

Comment: This is no doubt a good idea, but it would be more helpful to explain to the OP "how" to do it as much as "what:" do to. I would add some code to your answer.

Comment: Could you give example , i have over thousands of numbers under each other in that url, but it prints everything next to each other.